# Change in the audio samples when reading directly from the file using RandomAcessFile?

Tags: android, audio, sampling

Iam trying to draw a graph of a sound file. I am doing in such a way that i take the bytes of the sound file using Fileinputstream and change it to the shorts and take the samples of of the sound and draw the graph according to that note:first 45 bytes are header so i skip these bytes.And i succeeded in doing this.

```
File-->skip header(44)-->Bytes-->to shorts-->seek to point-->take samples in Shorts-->DRAW THE GRAPH
```

But the problem is, I cant take the bytes of large audio file(2GB) to memory. Memory crash occurs.

So tried reading the shorts directly from the file using RandomAcessfile. But when I do like this am not getting a correct graph. I hope there is some sort change in samples am reading.

```
File-->skip header(44)-->seek to point-->take samples in Shorts-->DRAW THE GRAPH
```

My doubt is, any change occurs to the short samples of an audio data when we read directly from the file??RandomAcessFile is a good method? Is there any way to get the samples of a 2GB audio file without any change in samples.

Note:I skip the header first 44 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    double mPerwidth = (double) iPixel / 960;
                    int SampletoDraw;
                    long totalLen = mRfs.length() - 44;
                    SampletoDraw = (int) (totalLen * mPerwidth) * 2;
                    System.out.println(iPixel);

                    // val=mRfs.readShort()/2;
                    mRfs.seek(SampletoDraw);
                    bData[0] = mRfs.readByte();
                    mRfs.seek(SampletoDraw + 1);
                    bData[1] = mRfs.readByte();

                    val = (short) ((bData[1] & 0xff) << 8 | (bData

                                    [0] & 0xff));
```